# How to convince others to effect change?

Tags: coding-standards, anti-patterns

I'm low man on the totem pole (consultant) who was pulled into a project for a large organization. How do you explain that this large organization practices zero industry standards and follows no software patterns? Yet everyone seems completely happy and convinced that nothing is wrong.

This is the least maintainable, least testable code I have seen in my 20 years of software development.

ALL logic/html/style/js is in the database procedures.

How do I persuade even 1 person that there is a better way?

Comment: **Lack of industry standards and patterns is a poor argument.**  I've seen systems that are decidedly non-standard and exotic that run circles around  more orthodox systems.  You have to figure out what the goals and objectives of the "others" are, and show them things that will help them better meet those specific goals.  If your goals don't align with theirs, that's a different problem altogether.

Comment: Unfortunately I will probably just have to sit back and collect a paycheck for being inefficient and under-utilized.  I'm not sure how putting all layers of an App in a single DB stored procedure can be acceptable.

Comment: Or, you can drop the insistence on the use of industry standards (if there is such a thing), and show them things that help them in ways that they want to be helped.  See also http://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: Following "no industry standards" **is the standard!**

Comment: @RobertHarvey With regards to the xkcd, God has forbidden the emergence of a single standard [since about 600BC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Babel). We need to get over it.

Comment: Come on, if everyone is happy, why have you been pulled into that project as a consultant? To my experience, consultants are asked when not everyone is happy, and there are some problems in the organziation.

Comment: [How do I explain ${something} to ${someone}?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/6630/31260)

Comment: Forget standards, but since when was the DB suppose to house the UI components of an application?  Ive certainly been at fault of putting to much business logic in the DB, but I don't do that anymore.

Comment: -1 for not beeing honest in your question. Below you wrote *"constant bugs, unable to fix problems quickly, unable to bring new folks on board"* which shows you are blatantly lying above- people cannot be happy with that. You need to bring **the problems on the table** - and that is where your focus must be when you try to improve something.

Comment: You are accusing me of not being honest?  whatever Doc.

Comment: @user52212: I am exxagerating a little bit to for the sake of the argument, of course - there is a hard discrepancy between saying "everyone is happy" and the description I copied from the comment below. Fact is, you can only change something in an organization if there are people having a certain need for change.

Comment: I said everyone [seems] completely happy, but thats because Im new on the project (6 months).  I shouldn't make that assumption, but I do sense that the core team in charge is very unlikely to change.

Comment: Example:  I call a procedure with 15 parameters, just do do a simple "Select by ID" operation, so I send 14 NULL parameters because I am forced to call an existing Oracle procedure that does way more than I need.  They write 1 procedure to handle all scenarios (bad performance).  The guy is happy with that design because he forces me to use it.

Comment: @user52212: can you prove the performance does not match the requirements by writing a test? Or can you prove that the function has bugs by writing some tests? Or do you have a more readable alternative for that 15 parameters call which you can provide? Did you consider to write some adapters with less parameters, encapsulating the calls to the 15 parameter function, to make the usage more smooth? I would work on these points.

Comment: If you build a bridge or a garage you have to follow building codes.  Isn't is ironic there are no building codes for code?

Answer (score 7):

> How do I persuade even 1 person that there is a better way?

You talk to them. You show them.

But it does not matter at all. Two people, even ten people aren't going to shift the culture of a large organization.

The org likes things the way they are now. They've incentivized people to do things the way they are now. People were rewarded and promoted for building what is there now, so see them as good. And the org has been very successful doing things the way things have been done, so see them as good.

The low man on the totem pole is never going to change that in an org of any significant size.

Comment: very well said.  I completely agree.  Im just shocked that an entire group could carry on with such buggy/unmaintainable/un-testable code.  I feel helpless adding another parameter to a procedure that is 3000 lines long

Comment: In this case, the best you can do is to be aware of the situation is paradigmatic and there're others way to do the things. I came to the conclusion that our career is in certain degree, "kindaped" by the company polices, practices and needs. So the best we can do is to don't fall in the false assumption that : "this is how things should be done". Keep being critic, but don't try to convince others to be too.

Comment: very well said.  I agree, just hate to bill a client when I am forced to be so inefficient

Comment: I disagree. A single person can make a big difference if they gain trust from the coworkers and are able to show concrete improvements with a tangle payoff, and can present it a way where it doesn't antagonize the powers that be. But just shouting "You fools, you don't use enough patterns! We need more patterns!" is probably not going to cut it.

Answer (score 4):

It's a long, hard slog to map out the advantages to be had from adopting best practice I'm afraid.  The best advice I can give is to try and find a middleweight problem - a bug which has cost a fair amount of time and trouble to fix for example, maybe with more than one attempt to fix - and map out how much time and money would have been saved were the product correctly structured - or at least structured differently. Try to put it in terms of "this is working for you, but imagine how much more time you would have and how much less stress there would be if we could find a better way".

There are lots of patterns and practices blogs, articles and white papers around from reputable sources which you can use to support your argument, but above all I would advise taking the "wouldn't it be great if..." approach rather than the "you guys must be crazy for..." approach.  You want them to want to improve, not feel like they're being criticized for practices which, as far as they're concerned, are perfectly reasonable and have served them well.

I've recently had to perform some major surgery on a mature product because things were structured badly, and I managed to win through because in tweaking the project I got some significant performance improvements and dramatically improved the stability of the product.  It might be worth finding an area of your product which you can start shaping in this way, but make sure people know what you're doing and why.  Ultimately it's a business decision, and if you can make it a bit of a no-brainer which delivers major improvements in process and output then your task will be all the easier.

Good luck to you!

Comment: Unfortunately there are a lot of egos at hand, and I will be very difficult to convince anybody.  I'm a staff aug consultant who was not brought in for opinion.  I'm just shocked as to how over-burfended and swamped the core team is because of all the bug-iness and unmaintainable code.  I've never seen ALL layers in 1 DB procedure.  And I've seen a lot in my 20 years.

Comment: "who was not brought in for opinion" -- Key phrase, there.  Though that seems at odds with the word "consultant."

Comment: I feel your pain, believe me.  You might find that outside the dev unit, they have a terrible reputation for late delivery and poor quality.  Unfortunately, you may be right, and you may have to just suck it up and do the best you can.  It'll be something to tell more enlightened developers about in the future at least!

Comment: as a consultant....sometimes we are "staff augmentation"...and not brought in to provide opinion, but to be another warm body on the team.

Comment: Are you the first or only staff augmentation consultant this organization has brought in? If there were others, how did they deal with the situation? How do new permanent hires ramp up? Do they have a hard time recruiting new developers? It seems like a major disadvantage of their unconventional ways would be getting new team members (perm hire or staff aug) up to speed.

Comment: But if it all works for them and they don't have issues with ramp-up, recruiting or retention, then maybe it's just a poor fit and you should move on. If enough consultants quit, maybe they'll figure it out.

Comment: All other consulting companies have failed.  It is very difficult to bring on new hires because ALL logic/layers are inside Oracle procedures.  Since this is the core app, all other Apps (new and old) are required to interfere and adhere to the same concepts, e.g. use mongo stored procedures , borrow existing large procedures for even the simplest of CRUD operations.  Im trying to understand why a team would write an Enterprise App this way?  The HTML and CSS is even buried inside procedures.  Its a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: I think they have problems in all the areas mentioned above.  Hence I'm trying to comprehend how teams continue to go down such a road.  This is truly an extreme case in my 20 years of software dev.

Comment: Never lose the control of your career. If something smell in your job, don't just sit back an wait for the next payrolls. If you are totally convinced that the job smells. Move yourself!! For the good of your career. You can not save everyone from their complacency.

Comment: Laiv well said!!

Comment: As far as trying to understand how teams can go down this road, I've seen it start when there is high skill but low judgement. You get folks who know a small set of tools really well, and rather than learn new tools, they have the skill (in the old tools) to solve problems that the tool was not meant to solve. Often their battle cry is "it's a poor craftsman who blames his tools." They like to reinvent wheels, both because they can (skill), and because they don't have the good sense not to (judgement).

Comment: Very well said Joe Ballard.

Comment: Joe your comment is absolutely what is happening in this case,  and its costing the company many many thousands of dollars.  I've seen it numerous times, just not on this large of an Enterprise scale.

Comment: @JoeBallard in one comment you've summed up the collective pain of a million developers inheriting projects from Founding Fathers!  Very well put!

Answer (score 2):

> How do you explain that this large organization practices zero
>   industry standards and follows no software patterns? Yet everyone seems completely happy and convinced that nothing is wrong.

Like this: *Wow! This large organization doesn't do any of the things I was told are good! And they even do things I was told are bad! But, this very successful organization doesn't seem to mind. What am I overlooking? Can I learn something from them? What problems are they trying to solve by hiring me?*

> This is the least maintainable, least testable code I have seen in my
>   20 years of software development.

I expect mostly anything outside your comfort zone will feel *unwieldy* and *bad* to you. But, if you can't break things down and articulate why they're bad for the company, why they're in opposition to its goals, your concern isn't necessarily rational; you're just uncomfortable. And the company can tolerate your discomfort.

> How do I persuade even 1 person that there is a better way?

Identify problems the company *actually has.*

These things are not inherent problems:

- Not adhering to standards
- Not using software patterns
- The code isn't unit tested
- "ALL logic/html/style/js is in the database procedures"

Inherently, they're just "things." They only attain the status of "problems" if they lead to more important "actual problems." Problems the company might care about sound like this:

- "Chrome is going to choke on our non-standard markup during the next update, and our core web property will totally be unusable."
- "It'll take us about a month to propagate that header change across the whole site."
- "We've been playing whack-a-mole with the same three recurring bugs for like 2 months now..."

If your company recognizes the problems and acknowledges that they are priorities, you can start talking about feasible solutions and how much of a time-investment the solutions are worth. But, be prepared! They may hear you out and say, "What you're calling problems aren't really problems for us," or "What we have is working for now," and "The proposed solutions aren't a net gain for us."

Bear in mind, you've been hired to do a particular job at a company that's already succeeding *in some ways.* You may have some great concerns and stellar sounding principles, but you may also be missing the company's "big picture." You will get no support from the company if there's no connection between your principles as theirs.

Answer (score 0):

First you should probably consider if "your way" actually *is* better. If everyone is happy and don't perceive any problems, then they must be doing *something* right. If they are achieving their goals without following the "industry standard", then perhaps they have unwittingly developed a process which is actually better than the industry standard?

It is *really* hard to sell a process change to somebody who don't perceive a problem with their current approach. You have to be able to show that the changes you suggest actually is an improvement. You definitely have to come up with better arguments than stating the code is not "industry standard" or "doesn't use patterns", since neither is something of value in itself.

Comment: constant bugs, unable to fix problems quickly, unable to bring new folks on board, having the core guys overwhelmed yet the rest of us sit around and do nothing.  These are real issues.  Its not about MY way, its about being open-minded and assessing.  I'm not a control freak.  I'm just amazed

Comment: Perhaps I should share a code snippet?  :)

Comment: @user52212: These are are indeed real problems, as opposed to the pseudo-problems you mention in the original question. So you should start with the real problems and then find some real improvements.

Answer (score 0):

First, find some evidence for the **real** problems of the organization. Above you wrote

> practices zero industry standards

I don't see a problem here.

> and follows no software patterns

Still no problem.

> This is the least maintainable, least testable code I have seen in my 20 years of software development.

Thats only a general, opinionated rating, no concrete problem.

> ALL logic/html/style/js is in the database procedures

I am pretty sure a team of good software engineers could build a well structured system using PL/SQL and Oracle as a platform - so still no problem given in that sentence.

So in your question, there is not much evidence that there is a need for any kind of change. But in a comment you wrote

> constant bugs, unable to fix problems quickly, unable to bring new folks on board, having the core guys overwhelmed yet the rest of us sit around and do nothing

Well, here are the interesting issues you "forgot" to mention in your question. But still you need to find out more about the root causes of these things, then you may be able to improve things.

- Constant bugs? Sounds quality assurance and testing needs to be improved. Maybe introducing some automated tests may help (don't tell me this is not possible because everything is in the DB - I wrote testing code in PL/SQL almost 20 years ago).
- Unable to fix problems quickly? Can have different reasons, find the root causes. Maybe debugging and logging tools are missing, maybe the documentation is bad, maybe people need more training, maybe the code is badly readable. Find the cause, then you can work on it.
- Unable to bring new folks on board? Find the cause. Is it because the system is so badly documented? Is more training needed? Or is it because no newcomer knows PL/SQL? Maybe there are possibilities to develop some new parts with a different tool set.

(And often a topic: do these folks have already heard of using source control?)

And so on. Sure, there will be also political problems to solve, which is nothing we can help you with (best recommendation here: find people who support you). But don't try to change the whole organization at once. Find an issue where you have a certain amount of influence, set a realistic goal for a slight improvement, try to implement it and make it public after it works. Rinse and repeat. If you are lucky, others will follow your example after some time.